# DTD error in my XML: the content of element type "exchange" must match

Tags: xml, dtd

I cannot figure this out.  I am using http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ to validate my internal DTD on the following document.  I keep getting the above error, and for the life of me cannot figure it out..  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>

<!DOCTYPE exchanges[

<!ELEMENT exchanges (exchange*)>
<!ATTLIST exchange exchangeType (S|T) #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST exchange id ID #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT exchange (name, address, telephone, emailAddress, applicationDate, availableDate, birthCountry, dateOfBirth?, age?, gender, schoolAddress, yearInSchool?, motherName?, fatherName?, emergencyTelephone, feePaid, essay, spokenLanguages, countryChoices)>
<!ELEMENT name (lastName, firstName, middleInitial?)>
<!ELEMENT lastName (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT firstName (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT middleInitial (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT address (street, apartment?, city, (state|province), (zipCode|postalCode), country)>
<!ELEMENT street (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT apartment (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT state (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT province (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT zipCode (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT postalCode (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT country (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT telephone (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT emailAddress (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT applicationDate (month, day, year)>
<!ELEMENT month (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT day (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT availableDate (month, day, year)>
<!ELEMENT birthCountry (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT dateOfBirth (month, day, year)>
<!ELEMENT age (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT gender (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT schoolName (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT schoolAddress (street, apartment?, city, (state|province), (zipCode|postalCode), country)>
<!ELEMENT yearInSchool (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT motherName (lastName, firstName, middleInitial?)>
<!ELEMENT fatherName (lastName, firstName, middleInitial?)>
<!ELEMENT emergencyTelephone (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT feePaid (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST feePaid currency CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT essay (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT spokenLanguages (language, language, language*)>
<!ATTLIST language fluency (1|2|3|4) #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT language (#PCDATA)>
<!ENTITY eng "English">
<!ENTITY spa "Spanish">
<!ENTITY jap "Japanese">
<!ENTITY fre "French">

<!ELEMENT countryChoices (countryChoice, countryChoice, countryChoice, countryChoice, countryChoice)>
<!ATTLIST countryChoice rank (1|2|3|4|5) #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT countryChoice (#PCDATA)>
<!ENTITY me "Mexico">
<!ENTITY ca "Canada">
<!ENTITY us "United States">
<!ENTITY br "Brazil">
<!ENTITY jp "Japan">
<!ENTITY it "Italy">

]>

<exchanges>
    <exchange id="I00001" exchangeType="S">
        <name>
            <lastName>StudentLastName</lastName>
            <firstName>StudentFirstName</firstName>
            <middleInitial>I</middleInitial>    
        </name>
        <address>
            <street>1701 Wright Street</street>
            <apartment></apartment>
            <city>Madison</city>
            <state>WI</state>
            <zipCode>53704</zipCode>
            <country>United States</country>
        </address>
        <telephone>(608) 555-1234</telephone>
        <emailAddress>studentemail@madisoncollege.edu</emailAddress>
        <applicationDate>
            <month>3</month>
            <day>23</day>
            <year>2015</year>
        </applicationDate>
        <availableDate>
            <month>3</month>
            <day>25</day>
            <year>2015</year>
        </availableDate>
        <birthCountry>United States</birthCountry>
        <dateOfBirth>
            <month>1</month>
            <day>22</day>
            <year>1997</year>
        </dateOfBirth>
        <age>18</age>
        <gender>male</gender>
        <schoolName>Madison Area High School</schoolName>
        <schoolAddress>
            <street>123 School Street</street>
            <city>Madison</city>
            <state>WI</state>
            <zipCode>53717</zipCode>
            <country>USA</country>
        </schoolAddress>
        <yearInSchool>Senior</yearInSchool>
        <motherName>
            <lastName>StudentParent</lastName>
            <firstName>Mom</firstName>
            <middleInitial>H</middleInitial>            
        </motherName>
        <fatherName>
            <lastName>StudentParent</lastName>
            <firstName>Dad</firstName>
            <middleInitial>K</middleInitial>
        </fatherName>
        <emergencyTelephone>(608) 123-4567</emergencyTelephone>
        <feePaid currency="USD">500.00</feePaid>
        <essay>
            <![CDATA[
            Sample of exchange essay for me to apply.  Why do I want to go?
            ]]>
        </essay>
        <spokenLanguages>
            <language fluency="3">German</language>
            <language fluency="3">English</language>
            <language fluency="1">Spanish</language>
        </spokenLanguages>
        <countryChoices>
            <countryChoice rank="1">Germany</countryChoice>
            <countryChoice rank="3">Brazil</countryChoice>
            <countryChoice rank="5">Mexico</countryChoice>
            <countryChoice rank="2">France</countryChoice>
            <countryChoice rank="4">England</countryChoice>
        </countryChoices>
    </exchange>

    <exchange id="I00002" exchangeType="S">
        <name>
            <lastName>Smith-William</lastName>
            <firstName>Julian</firstName>
            <middleInitial>J</middleInitial>    
        </name>
        <address>
            <street>123 Some Street</street>
            <apartment></apartment>
            <city>Portland</city>
            <state>OR</state>
            <zipCode>12345</zipCode>
            <country>United States</country>
        </address>
        <telephone>(123) 123-4567</telephone>
        <emailAddress>smith-william@madisoncollege.edu</emailAddress>
        <applicationDate>
            <month>1</month>
            <day>14</day>
            <year>2015</year>
        </applicationDate>
        <availableDate>
            <month>2</month>
            <day>13</day>
            <year>2015</year>
        </availableDate>
        <birthCountry>United States</birthCountry>
        <dateOfBirth>
            <month>4</month>
            <day>5</day>
            <year>1998</year>
        </dateOfBirth>
        <age>16</age>
        <gender>male</gender>
        <schoolName>Westview High School</schoolName>
        <schoolAddress>
            <street>44566 Westview Road</street>
            <city>Portland</city>
            <state>Oregon</state>
            <zipCode>12345</zipCode>
            <country>United States</country>
        </schoolAddress>
        <yearInSchool>Junior</yearInSchool>
        <motherName>
            <lastName>Smith</lastName>
            <firstName>Peggy</firstName>
            <middleInitial>H</middleInitial>            
        </motherName>
        <fatherName>
            <lastName>Williams</lastName>
            <firstName>Ralph</firstName>
            <middleInitial>Y</middleInitial>
        </fatherName>
        <emergencyTelephone>(608) 555-4456</emergencyTelephone>
        <feePaid currency="USD">50.00</feePaid>
        <essay>
            <![CDATA[
            I have worked all my life and would like to travel. In order for me to be considered to 
            be a foreign exchange student, I would need a scholarship.
            ]]>
        </essay>
        <spokenLanguages>
            <language fluency="2">Greek</language>
            <language fluency="4">English</language>
        </spokenLanguages>
        <countryChoices>
            <countryChoice rank="2">Finland</countryChoice>
            <countryChoice rank="5">Norway</countryChoice>
            <countryChoice rank="1">Brazil</countryChoice>
            <countryChoice rank="3">Japan</countryChoice>
            <countryChoice rank="4">Egypt</countryChoice>
        </countryChoices>
    </exchange>

    <exchange id="I00003" exchangeType="S">
        <name>
            <lastName>Morimoto</lastName>
            <firstName>Vivian</firstName>
            <middleInitial></middleInitial> 
        </name>
        <address>
            <street>112 Japan Street</street>
            <city>Bunkyo-ku</city>
            <province>Tokyo</province>
            <postalCode>100-6805</postalCode>
            <country>Japan</country>
        </address>
        <telephone>(111) 222-3333</telephone>
        <emailAddress>vmorimoto@madisoncollege.edu</emailAddress>
        <applicationDate>
            <month>1</month>
            <day>6</day>
            <year>2015</year>
        </applicationDate>
        <availableDate>
            <month>2</month>
            <day>13</day>
            <year>2015</year>
        </availableDate>
        <birthCountry>Japan</birthCountry>
        <dateOfBirth>
            <month>9</month>
            <day>3</day>
            <year>1997</year>
        </dateOfBirth>
        <age>17</age>
        <gender>female</gender>
        <schoolName>Tokyo's Finest High School</schoolName>
        <schoolAddress>
            <street>1223 High School Street</street>
            <city>Bunkyo-ku</city>
            <province>Tokyo</province>
            <postalCode>100-6805</postalCode>
            <country>Japan</country>
        </schoolAddress>
        <yearInSchool>Junior</yearInSchool>
        <motherName>
            <lastName>Morimoto</lastName>
            <firstName>Tina</firstName>
            <middleInitial>K</middleInitial>            
        </motherName>
        <fatherName>
            <lastName>Morimoto</lastName>
            <firstName>Katsumoto</firstName>
            <middleInitial>Q</middleInitial>
        </fatherName>
        <emergencyTelephone>(608) 555-2222</emergencyTelephone>
        <feePaid currency="JPY">1000.00</feePaid>
        <essay>
            <![CDATA[
            This would be a great opportunity for me to get out and see the world. I truly enjoy
            living in Japan, but I would also love to travel around the world and this opportunity
            would give me a chance to do so.  France would be a dream trip, but going to the United
            States would also be quite wonderful.  Those are my top two choices, but in the end--any
            opportunity to go to any country would be an absolute thrill!!
            ]]>
        </essay>
        <spokenLanguages>
            <language fluency="3">Engish</language>
            <language fluency="4">Japanese</language>
            <language fluency="2">French</language>
        </spokenLanguages>
        <countryChoices>
            <countryChoice rank="2">United States</countryChoice>
            <countryChoice rank="4">Germany</countryChoice>
            <countryChoice rank="3">Canada</countryChoice>
            <countryChoice rank="5">Italy</countryChoice>
            <countryChoice rank="1">France</countryChoice>
        </countryChoices>
    </exchange>

    <exchange id="I000004" exchangeType="T">
        <name>
            <lastName>Walden</lastName>
            <firstName>Mary-Jo</firstName>
            <middleInitial>U</middleInitial>    
        </name>
        <address>
            <street>333 North Shore Blvd</street>
            <apartment>310</apartment>
            <city>Miami</city>
            <state>FL</state>
            <zipCode>32408</zipCode>
            <country>United States</country>
        </address>
        <telephone>(555) 222-4456</telephone>
        <emailAddress>teacher@madisoncollege.edu</emailAddress>
        <applicationDate>
            <month>5</month>
            <day>22</day>
            <year>2014</year>
        </applicationDate>
        <availableDate>
            <month>6</month>
            <day>1</day>
            <year>2015</year>
        </availableDate>
        <birthCountry>Canada</birthCountry>
        <gender>female</gender>
        <schoolName>Simple High School</schoolName>
        <schoolAddress>
            <street>1223 Some Nice Street</street>
            <city>Miami</city>
            <state>FL</state>
            <zipCode>32417</zipCode>
            <country>United States</country>
        </schoolAddress>
        <emergencyTelephone>(333) 435-3423</emergencyTelephone>
        <feePaid currency="USD">200.00</feePaid>
        <essay>
            <![CDATA[
            I am coming to bring my knowledge and experience to others, but more so to learn
            from others and become a better person.
            ]]>
        </essay>
        <spokenLanguages>
            <language fluency="2">German</language>
            <language fluency="4">English</language>
            <language fluency="3">Japanese</language>
        </spokenLanguages>
        <countryChoices>
            <countryChoice rank="4">Germany</countryChoice>
            <countryChoice rank="1">Japan</countryChoice>
            <countryChoice rank="3">Brazil</countryChoice>
            <countryChoice rank="5">Germany</countryChoice>
            <countryChoice rank="2">France</countryChoice>
        </countryChoices>
    </exchange>
</exchanges>
```

Thanks again to anyone who can help!

Comment: Don't forget to vote on the answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You have `schoolName` as a child element of each `exchange`, but it is not defined in your DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT exchange (name, address, telephone, emailAddress, applicationDate,
availableDate, birthCountry, dateOfBirth?, age?, gender, schoolAddress, yearInSchool?,
motherName?, fatherName?, emergencyTelephone, feePaid, essay,
spokenLanguages, countryChoices)>
```

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure if there are any DTD validation tools which will produce a more helpful message (i.e. pointing at the element violating the schema). In any case, [XSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C))s offer more possibilities for validation than DTD, and will make pinpointing the error easier.